# Building PubNub C++ with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, pubnub, clion

I'm trying to compile a sample from the [PubNub C++ git repository](https://github.com/pubnub/c-core) using CMake to include the library it in one of my projects.

As a test, I chose to compile the sample named 
**cancel_subscribe_sync_sample** from the [provided Makefile](https://github.com/pubnub/c-core/blob/master/cpp/posix.mk).

Using the Makefile, it compiles without any error.

This is the CMakeLists I came up with (I am no expert in CMake) :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES cancel_subscribe_sync_sample.cpp)

set(PUBNUB_FILES c-core/core/pubnub_coreapi.c
        c-core/core/pubnub_coreapi_ex.c
        c-core/core/pubnub_ccore.c
        c-core/core/pubnub_netcore.c
        c-core/lib/sockets/pbpal_sockets.c
        c-core/lib/sockets/pbpal_resolv_and_connect_sockets.c
        c-core/core/pubnub_alloc_std.c
        c-core/core/pubnub_assert_std.c
        c-core/core/pubnub_generate_uuid.c
        c-core/core/pubnub_blocking_io.c
        c-core/core/pubnub_timers.c
        c-core/core/pubnub_json_parse.c
        c-core/core/pubnub_helper.c
        c-core/posix/pubnub_version_posix.c
        c-core/posix/pubnub_generate_uuid_posix.c
        c-core/posix/pbpal_posix_blocking_io.c
        c-core/posix/monotonic_clock_get_time_posix.c)

include_directories(c-core/posix)
include_directories(c-core/cpp)
include_directories(c-core/core)

add_definitions(-DPUBNUB_THREADSAFE)

add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES} c-core/core/pubnub_ntf_sync.c c-core/cpp/pubnub_futres_sync.cpp ${PUBNUB_FILES})
link_libraries(untitled pthread rt)
```

Using it with CLion on Ubuntu, the compilation fails with :

```
/home/barrauh/clion-2016.1/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/barrauh/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/untitled-609ca616/609ca616/Debug --target untitled -- -j 4
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/cancel_subscribe_sync_sample.cpp.o
[  9%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_ntf_sync.c.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/cpp/pubnub_futres_sync.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_coreapi.c.o
[ 23%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_coreapi_ex.c.o
[ 28%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_ccore.c.o
[ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_netcore.c.o
[ 38%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/lib/sockets/pbpal_sockets.c.o
[ 42%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/lib/sockets/pbpal_resolv_and_connect_sockets.c.o
[ 47%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_alloc_std.c.o
[ 52%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_assert_std.c.o
[ 57%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_generate_uuid.c.o
[ 61%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_blocking_io.c.o
[ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_timers.c.o
[ 71%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_json_parse.c.o
[ 76%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_helper.c.o
[ 80%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/posix/pubnub_version_posix.c.o
[ 85%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/posix/pubnub_generate_uuid_posix.c.o
[ 90%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/posix/pbpal_posix_blocking_io.c.o
[ 95%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/posix/monotonic_clock_get_time_posix.c.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable untitled
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/cancel_subscribe_sync_sample.cpp.o: In function `pubnub::context::context(std::string, std::string)':
/home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/cpp/pubnub_common.hpp:201: undefined reference to `pubnub_alloc()'
/home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/cpp/pubnub_common.hpp:205: undefined reference to `pubnub_init(pubnub_*, char const*, char const*)'
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/cancel_subscribe_sync_sample.cpp.o: In function `pubnub::context::get() const':
/home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/cpp/pubnub_common.hpp:267: undefined reference to `pubnub_get(pubnub_*)'
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/cancel_subscribe_sync_sample.cpp.o: In function `pubnub::context::cancel()':
/home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/cpp/pubnub_common.hpp:305: undefined reference to `pubnub_cancel(pubnub_*)'
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/cancel_subscribe_sync_sample.cpp.o: In function `pubnub::context::subscribe(std::string const&, std::string const&)':
/home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/cpp/pubnub_common.hpp:328: undefined reference to `pubnub_subscribe(pubnub_*, char const*, char const*)'
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/cancel_subscribe_sync_sample.cpp.o: In function `pubnub::context::set_blocking_io(pubnub::blocking_io)':
/home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/cpp/pubnub_common.hpp:537: undefined reference to `pubnub_set_blocking_io(pubnub_*)'
/home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/cpp/pubnub_common.hpp:540: undefined reference to `pubnub_set_non_blocking_io(pubnub_*)'
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/cancel_subscribe_sync_sample.cpp.o: In function `pubnub::context::~context()':
/home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/cpp/pubnub_common.hpp:580: undefined reference to `pubnub_free(pubnub_*)'
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/cpp/pubnub_futres_sync.cpp.o: In function `pubnub::futres::last_result()':
/home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/cpp/pubnub_futres_sync.cpp:34: undefined reference to `pubnub_last_result(pubnub_*)'
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/cpp/pubnub_futres_sync.cpp.o: In function `pubnub::futres::end_await()':
/home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/cpp/pubnub_futres_sync.cpp:50: undefined reference to `pubnub_await(pubnub_*)'
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_coreapi.c.o: In function `pubnub_init':
/home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/core/pubnub_coreapi.c:20: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
/home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/core/pubnub_coreapi.c:20: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [untitled] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [untitled] Error 2titled/c-core/cpp/pubnub_common.hpp:580: undefined reference to `pubnub_free(pubnub_*)'
    CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/cpp/pubnub_futres_sync.cpp.o: In function `pubnub::futres::last_result()':
    /home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/cpp/pubnub_futres_sync.cpp:34: undefined reference to `pubnub_last_result(pubnub_*)'
    CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/cpp/pubnub_futres_sync.cpp.o: In function `pubnub::futres::end_await()':
    /home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/cpp/pubnub_futres_sync.cpp:50: undefined reference to `pubnub_await(pubnub_*)'
    CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/c-core/core/pubnub_coreapi.c.o: In function `pubnub_init':
    /home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/core/pubnub_coreapi.c:20: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
    /home/barrauh/ClionProjects/untitled/c-core/core/pubnub_coreapi.c:20: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[3]: *** [untitled] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule] Error 2
    make: *** [untitled] Error 2
```

I really don't understand why. For exemple, the function *pubnub_alloc()* is defined in the file **pubnub_alloc_std.c**.

It's driving me nuts... Am I doing something wrong here ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is, that the 'pubnub_alloc_std.c' file is compiled with a C compiler (i guess `gcc`). C uses different [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) than C++, so one needs to tell the C++ compiler that those functions use C name mangling. One commonly does that using the `extern "C"` specifier.

However, this seems to be commented out in this file:
https://github.com/pubnub/c-core/blob/master/cpp/pubnub_common.hpp (line 5-14)

Two possible solutions:

1. try commenting the `extern "C"` section back in
2. compile the c files using a C++ compiler. You can do that by running cmake with the flag `-DCMAKE_C_COMILER=g++`

Comment: It's working great now. I uncommented some of the `extern "C"` and voila !
I had no idea this specifier exist.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -std=c++11 -D PUBNUB_USE_EXTERN_C=1")